# How to run Firefox headless in seleniumwire?

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumwire

I'm trying to run selenium-wire with Firefox in headless mode:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://user:password@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://user:password@ip:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    },
    'headless': True
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
driver.get("http://adream.es")
```

It's not making any effect because the browser window still pops up :(

In selenium normally I was running it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://adream.es")
```

How can I run it headless?

Answer (score 1):

I had to check into the seleniumwire files, this combination worked for me

```py
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from seleniumwire import webdriver as seleniumwire_webdriver
fireFoxOptions = FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.headless = True

seleniumwire_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://user:password@ip:port',
        'https': 'https://user:password@ip:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    options=fireFoxOptions,
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options )
```

happy scraping

Comment: but with your code I loose the proxy

Comment: you should still be able to include the seleniumwire options (it's a separate argument), have did you try that?